# cassandra cql filter data with date in where clause

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cassandra, cql

What is the right cql to query a subset of records created today, this month etc.

I believe every column stores a timestamp along with the value, hence I am not storing it separately. Can I use this and how? or do I need to add another column for date the record is created?

I am trying to use following links to achieve this:
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html
https://github.com/kreynolds/cassandra-cql

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with `writetime()` on this or did you have to track it separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `writetime(<column>)` function to get the storage engine's timestamp.

Querying with this will always require a sequential scan, so it's only really appropriate for batch analysis.

Comment: I want to write a query like this: select * from Activities where writetime(status) = current_date;

Comment: `writetime()` cannot be used in the where clause. Far as I can tell it is useless for the OP's question.